# Java Program to count matching parenthesis

Tags: java

I want to write a program to count the number of matching parenthesis. Can anyone know how to write it?
For ex. Input ((This is )((a test)
        Output=2

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you thinking about approaching the problem? Is this homework?

Comment: -1, can you add the code you have already tried? Look into String documentation.

Comment: do not expect source code from the community,u try when u fail seek help

Comment: Do you have to account for non-matching (randomly placed) open and/or close parens?

Answer (score 5):

- Iterate over the string, character by character.
- When you find an open parenthesis, increment an "open" counter
- When you find a closing parenthesis:

  - If your "open" counter is <= 0, ignore and continue (you've got a close without a matching open)
  - If your "open" counter is > 0, decrement your "open" counter, and increment a "matched" counter

Comment: +1. Finally, a simple, efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the characters in the string and keep track of the opening and closing parentheses.

Take a look at the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class which has methods to give you its [`length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) and to find the [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) a certain index.

Comment: why the downvote? this answer seems correct to me, might be missing something though :|

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it doesn't answer the question. What's the meaning of "keep track of"? The answer could as well be: "iterate, and count the matching parentheses", which doesn't help much.

Comment: by giving code examples u may avoid downvotes here.I 2 faced same prob,sharing exp.

Comment: Apologies, the original downvote was from me as it didn't answer the question. Your original answer wouldn't actually have counted the pairs. I was in the process of writing a comment and got called away.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack: when you find an opening parenthesis, push it onto a stack.  When you meet a closing parenthesis, pop one off.  When you reach the end of the statement, the stack with either be empty (all parentheses match) or the number left tells you how many failed to close.

Comment: There's not much point in keeping a stack, etc., unless there is more parsing to be done. Right now, this requirement could be met with a simple counter of "currently open" parentheses.

Comment: Though correct, a stack with only one possible character seems like an overkill, a counter as @dogbane should imitate this stack more efficiently.

Comment: "I want to write a program to count the number of matching paranthesis" - no requirement for more parsing.  I agree - counting would be sufficient.  But counting will pass on JB Nizet's result above, but a stack won't be fooled.  Where's your answer?  Or do you just troll and comment on other people's answers?

Comment: What does efficiency mean for a trivial problem as small as this?  Ridiculous.  And I see no requirement for additional characters.

Comment: @duffymo: commenting is encouraged, and the comment is not pointless. I don't see why it would be a troll. BTW, the question asks the number of matching parentheses, and your answer gives the number of non-matching opening ones.

Comment: @duffymo, if you're asking where my answer is, it was posted about 30 seconds after I commented on yours.

Comment: @duffymo: The voteup to your comment is a mistake, while trying to flag this comment as offensive and missclicking. Commenting non correct/non efficient answers is trolling? since when? P.S. "my" answer is given as a voteup to dogbane's answer, which is correct and gives guidelines, in my opinion.

Comment: Perhaps, but I prefer answers.  Have the courage of your convictions and see if you idea stands up to the voting process.